# Login in a user using AFNetworking 2 (or some other framework

Tags: afnetworking-2

I am trying to write some code to have a user enter their username and password and then authenticate against a server using basic HTTP authentication. I can do it using AFNetworking 2 BUT I want to be able to return whether or not the request was successful. The code below works, but how can I refactor it so that I can call the method and then return a BOOL true or false?? It is driving me crazy that I can't do this.

```
    - (void)authenticateWithUserEmail:(NSString *)pUserEmail
                     withUserPassword:(NSString *)pUserPassword {

      NSString *loginURL =
          @"https://mydomain/login";

      AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =
          [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
      manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
      [manager.requestSerializer
          setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:pUserEmail
                                         password:pUserPassword];
      manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

      AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager GET:loginURL
          parameters:[self jsonDict]
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSLog(@"Success");
          }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Failure");
          }];
      [operation start];
    }

    - (IBAction)btnAuthenticate:(id)sender {

      [self authenticateWithUserEmail:self.userEmail.text
                     withUserPassword:self.userPassword.text];

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the network call is performed asynchronously, you can't simply return a BOOL because the method returns as soon as you call `[operation start];`, at which point the network call hasn't completed. What you need to do is add a block parameter to your method that get's invoked in the completion or failure block of the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` So your method signature will look like this:

```
- (void)authenticateWithUserEmail:(NSString *)pUserEmail
                 withUserPassword:(NSString *)pUserPassword
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionBlock;
```

In this method, add to your success/failure blocks to invoke your new block parameter. Like so:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager GET:loginURL
      parameters:[self jsonDict]
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

          if (completionBlock) {
              completionBlock(YES);
          }

          NSLog(@"Success");
      }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

          if (completionBlock) {
              completionBlock(NO);
          }

          NSLog(@"Failure");
      }];
```

And your invocation of this method will now look like this:

```
- (IBAction)btnAuthenticate:(id)sender {

  [self authenticateWithUserEmail:self.userEmail.text
                 withUserPassword:self.userPassword.text
                 completion:^(BOOL success) {
                      if (success) {

                          //login successful, do stuff
                      } else {

                         //login failed, do other stuff
                      }
                 }];

}
```

This generally how to handle responding to asynchronous events, since you can't return something that hasn't been determined yet.

Comment: This is wonderful. Great, concise, and accurate explanation of the issue. I coded this and it worked as advertised. I believe there is one small error in the last line of the signature, you missed a ")" it should  be ompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionBlock;

Comment: Thank you! Edited to fix the typo